# Can't install app as .apk, but I can install it via USB-debugging

Tags: java, android, sdk, export

my app now finally is in the stage, that I'd like my friends to test it. I was always using it on my Nexus 4 via USB-debugging. 
Therefore I rightclicked my project -> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package. I tried to install it, but it says something like "Application not installed" (On my german OS: App wurde nicht installiert.)

I dont find a reason for that. Can somebody help me?

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

I've got Andorid 4.3

Comment: is the `Unknown sources` ticked in the device?

Comment: Make sure they have "Allow third party apps", or something similar, checked on their devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to do any thing special , Go eclipse-> your project -> Bin -> your app name.apk
 is available there you can copy and send it to all your friends for testing ....

while you want to upload your APK in Google market that you need  a signed APK .

otherwise you can use normal APK from BIN folder

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you